# How to save File info over restart

Tags: vb.net, dll

Ok so I have an application that when you click the "Browse" button if will open a File Dialog, in this dialog you select a DLL and it takes that file a sends it to a listbox.
(OpenFileDialog1 code:)

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\"))
    Dim DLLfileName As String = FileName.Replace("\", "")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(DLLfileName)
    dlls.Add(DLLfileName, OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim FileHistory As String = DLLfileName + "|" + OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    StrList.Add(FileHistory)
    ''Dim Stringtosplit As String() = Openfiledialog1namedata.Split("|")
    ''Dim Filenametoassign As String = Stringtosplit(0)
    ''Dim Pathtoassign As String = Stringtosplit(1)
    'MsgBox(Filenametoassign)
    'MsgBox(Pathtoassign)
End Sub
```

As you can see i'm splitting the info and my idea is to create a string/string collection that every time a DLL is chosen/added, it will have the Filename + Path saved so on the restart I can call it to re-populate the Listbox.

I've tried many methods and haven't had much luck. As I was only able to save the name of the DLL. Now I run into the problem of how can I save "Filenametoassign | Pathtoassign" to a separate string each time and then on the MyBase.Load call them to re-populate the Listbox via this command:

```
dlls.Add(DLLfileName, OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

(the Dim of dlls)

```
Dim dlls As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving to a textfile you could do something like this:

```
Dim sb as new System.Text.StringBuilder
For Each k as String in dlls.Keys
   sb.AppendLine(k & "|" & dlls(k))
Next
IO.File.WriteAllText(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "dlls.txt"), sb.ToString)
```

This creates a line for each loaded dll in the form `Key|Value` and writes it to a textfile.
To load it again you would do it like this:

```
If dlls Is Nothing then dlls = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dlls.Clear()
Dim DllFile As String = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "dlls.txt")
If IO.File.Exists(DllFile) = False Then Exit Sub
Dim LoadedDlls() as String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(DllFile)
For Each s As String in LoadedDlls
   Dim Parts() As String = Strings.Split(s, "|", 2)
   If Parts.Count <> 2 Then Continue For
   dlls.Add(Parts(0), Parts(1))
Next
```

This first loads all the lines from the file and generates a String array from them. It then iterates over all the lines and splits each line at the `|` character with a maximum of two parts. It then adds part 0 as the key and part 1 as the value to the Dictionary again.